# Javascript named, self-calling function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a couple bits of code that seem like they could be condensed but I'm not sure how.

The code I have is this

```
var checkForUnitReferred = function () {
    $("#LeadForm").toggle($("#Claim_UnitReferredNoNull").is(":checked"));
};
checkForUnitReferred();

$("#Claim_UnitReferredNoNull").change(function() {
    checkForUnitReferred();        
});
```

It basically checks if a checkbox is checked and displays a form, otherwise it hides it. What I would rather have is something like this

```
var checkForUnitReferred = (function() {
    $("#LeadForm").toggle($("#Claim_UnitReferredNoNull").is(":checked"));
})();

$("#Claim_UnitReferredNoNull").change(function() {
    checkForUnitReferred();        
});
```

I know this doesn't work but I think something like that would be cleaner. Anyone know of a way to accomplish this?

Comment: You mean you want to call `checkForUnitReferred` initially and then on each change event? I wouldn't say your second piece of code is necessarily any cleaner...

Comment: Yeah that's what I want to do, I just don't like declaring a function and then calling it immediately, I'd rather it be called when declared and be passable

Comment: +1 for hypnotoad...+1 for hypnotoad...+1 for hypnotoad...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
var checkForUnitReferred;

(checkForUnitReferred = function() {
    $("#LeadForm").toggle($("#Claim_UnitReferredNoNull").is(":checked"));
})();

$("#Claim_UnitReferredNoNull").change(function() {
    checkForUnitReferred();        
});
```

This is possible because the assignment (`=`) operator returns the value set.

Answer (score 2):

Name the function directly rather than create an anonymous one to assign to a variable. You may also assign this function as the `.change()` handler without the extra wrapper function:

```
(function checkForUnitReferred() {
    $("#LeadForm").toggle($("#Claim_UnitReferredNoNull").is(":checked"));
})();

$("#Claim_UnitReferredNoNull").change(checkForUnitReferred);
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me, works on page load but the change event is not firing.

Comment: @lonesomeday: Actually there is no hoisting here: the parentheses ensure that the function is parsed as a named function expression rather than a function declaration. That being the case, this has its own problems in IE and should probably be avoided: http://kangax.github.com/nfe/

Comment: @Tim, thanks for the link, I stand corrected. Although *because* of the bugs in IE, it's the only browser this works in.